# Excel display non error value from array

Tags: excel

I have a row of 6 values of which some may be #N/A. I want a formula to output the first or last non-N/A value.

Here are 2 rows as a sample. If these are in col A-F, formula would be in col G for each row. For row 1, the output can be either F or G (whatever the formula does by default) and for row 2, it must be B since it's the only non-error value in the row.

```
F       #N/A     #N/A     #N/A    G        #N/A
#N/A    B        #N/A     #N/A    #N/A     #N/A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work: it gives the value from the latest column to store a non-errored data:

```
=INDEX(A1:F1,MATCH("zzzzz",A1:F1,1))
```

It takes advantage of the fact that MATCH expects the data to be ordered, and on not finding the exact match "zzzzz", it finds the nearest ordered item.